# Simplest way to adjust UI for all iPhone sizes using xib

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am working on a iPhone app which required to be run on all iPhone sizes i.e. 4s,5,6 and 6 plus in ios 8 and above.
What will be the simplest way to adjust UI to support all screen sizes.
I am using Xib.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Autoresizing` is simplest way to adjust UI to support all screen sizes in portrait mode as @Nishant explained instead of using `constraints` in `AutoLayout`. But if you want adjust same UI in landscape and portrait both then use `AutoLayout` & `Size Classes` as @ezCoding explained.

Answer (score 3):

In your storyboard make sure that you are using the `Any Width | Any Height` settings:

[image]

Also make sure to check `Use AutoLayout`and `Use Size Classes`:

[image]

To understand it all take some time to [read this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial).

Comment: XIB too. It's the default settings when starting a new Project in iOS 8

Answer (score 2):

[image: Check the all iphone4,5,6 & 6+ size in xib]

[image: and set the layout int his pic]

you can set size here and check also..

Comment: Pretty old school. Not recommended anymore! iOS 8 and iOS 9 are with universal storyboards and auto layout...